# Express Pass Variable to Angular Without Templating Engine

Tags: angularjs, express

Question: Does this work without e.g. ejs/jade? And where is the difference between a framework like AngularJs and a templating engine?

E.g.

Server.js

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
```

Routes.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // res.render('index.ejs');
    res.sendfile('index.html', {
        user : "Tom"//req.user
    });
});
```

Index.html (Here I have no idea how to do this)

```
<body ng-app="App" id="App" ng-controller="RootCtrl as rootCtrl" ng-mouseleave="rootCtrl.exit()">
    <script> 
      // angular.module('$user', []).constant('$user', <%= user %>)
    </script>
    ....
```

Tutorials I looked into:

http://www.mircozeiss.com/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-a-server-to-angular/
http://www.linkplugapp.com/a/224929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should work, but you need to enable ejs in your express app.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

I did the same thing with laravel and blade.

Comment: Actually I try to avoid using ejs. It seems simple but I have the feeling for every problem I adress in my application I have to use another language or tool. So is there a solution with just plain angular and no ejs. That's the reason why I commented this out.

Comment: You cant pass data from the server directly to your html without template engine.